# Sniffing data on a network

Tags: networking, sniffing, gopro

I have a couple of GoPro's connected to a Smart Remote device. I am able to connect to the hidden wifi access point created by the Smart Remote. I want to observe the communication between the GoPro's and the Smart Remote. Is this possible? I mean to intercept the UDP packets which are exchanged between the GoPro's and Smart Remote?

Answer (score 1):

You will need a program like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and a means of grabbing all packets going over the netwerk. An old-school hub is the easiest method of achieving this (all ports get all packets) but they are no longer sold now-a-days. Your best bet is either a managed switch on which you configure a sniffer port which receives all the packets from the other ports or to add a second network port to your PC/laptop and turn it into a man-in-the-middle device.

If everything is wireless, including the sniffer PC, then Wireshark is able to capture everything flying through the ether and you won't need to bother with a cabled solution. A quick hint from the linked wiki page:

> When installed on Windows Vista or later (including Win7, Win8 and
>   Win10) with option "Support raw 802.11 traffic (and monitor mode) for
>   wireless adapters" selected, all the wireless adapters can be selected
>   in Wireshark so as to capture raw 802.11 traffic. In "monitor mode",
>   raw 802.11 packets (data + management + control) with radiotap header
>   can be see. Otherwise, only 802.11 data packets can be see. You can
>   enter "monitor mode" via Wireshark or WlanHelper.exe tool shipped with
>   Npcap.

Here's the direct link to the initial setup page: https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN

And here's a link that describes how to decrypt WiFi traffic. https://wiki.wireshark.org/HowToDecrypt802.11

Wireshark has some awesome manuals, wikis and tens-of-thousands of questions on StackExchange so I hope this answer gets you started.

Comment: Can you provide information on configuring Wireshark to capture WiFi traffic, decrypt it, etc...? Currently this answer has no real information other than "_it can be done_", and wired solutions are irrelevant here.

Comment: Actually I am already trying to use Wireshark. What I am doing right now is, on my laptop I connect to the smart remote. Then I connect the gopros as well to the smart remote. Next I start Wireshark in promiscuous mode. But I see only the data which is sent from the smart remote to my computer. What I need is to see the data transfer from gopro to smart remote and vice versa. What happens is, every device connected to the smart remote gets a dynamic IP. I can see the data between the computer and the smart remote. But other things? How to see the data?

Comment: @Chani The linked manual gives instructions on how to setup Wireshark for WiFi packet capture. I put in an extra quote on what I feel summarises what you have to do in the answer. Here's an additional link on how to decrypt WiFi traffic: [https://wiki.wireshark.org/HowToDecrypt802.11](https://wiki.wireshark.org/HowToDecrypt802.11)